# Revisions are listed, but none of them has content

Tags: 8, nodes

I observed that the *Revisions* tab lists an entry for every saved revision, but my Twig template doesn't show anything for them.

> [image]

Is this an issue with the Twig files using `{{ node.body.value|raw }}`, a configuration issue, or something else?

If it is a configuration issue, how do I enable revisions for the node.body and other fields in my content types?

**UPDATE 2017-06-29 **

The site's base theme is Bootstrap and we have a child theme developed by a third party.

Bootstrap's templates/system/page.html.twig prints body content using `{{ page.content }}`.

When I use `{{ page.content }}` in child theme page.html.twig I get fields other than Body expressed.

With debugging turned on here are the extraneous elements.  I need to sort out how to safely express just the body content in a way which the Revision previewer will also display them.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'links__node' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * links--node.html.twig
   x links.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/system/links.html.twig' -->

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/system/links.html.twig' -->



<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--node--field-banner-image--page.html.twig
   * field--node--field-banner-image.html.twig
   * field--node--page.html.twig
   * field--field-banner-image.html.twig
   * field--image.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

  <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/42/field_banner_image/en/full" class="field field--name-field-banner-image field--type-image field--label-visually_hidden">
    <div class="field--label sr-only">Banner Image</div>
              <div class="field--item">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/image/templates/image-formatter.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/system/image.html.twig' -->
<img src="/sites/default/files/2017-05/about-banner_1.jpg" width="1920" height="581" alt="" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" />

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/system/image.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/modules/image/templates/image-formatter.html.twig' -->

</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->



<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--node--field-banner-scroll-image--page.html.twig
   * field--node--field-banner-scroll-image.html.twig
   * field--node--page.html.twig
   * field--field-banner-scroll-image.html.twig
   * field--image.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

  <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/42/field_banner_scroll_image/en/full" class="field field--name-field-banner-scroll-image field--type-image field--label-visually_hidden">
    <div class="field--label sr-only">Banner Scroll Image</div>
              <div class="field--item">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/image/templates/image-formatter.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/system/image.html.twig' -->
<img src="/sites/default/files/default_images/page-scroll.png" width="63" height="63" alt="page scroll image" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" />

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/system/image.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/modules/image/templates/image-formatter.html.twig' -->

</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->



<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--node--field-banner-quote--page.html.twig
   * field--node--field-banner-quote.html.twig
   * field--node--page.html.twig
   * field--field-banner-quote.html.twig
   * field--text-with-summary.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

  <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/42/field_banner_quote/en/full" class="field field--name-field-banner-quote field--type-text-with-summary field--label-visually_hidden">
    <div class="field--label sr-only">Banner Quote</div>
              <div class="field--item"><h2>ABOUT Freeport-McMoRan</h2>
</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the issue is probably with your twig files. If your twig template gets the node from the current route, then `{{ node.body.value }}` won't work, because the route `entity.node.revision` doesn't provide a node entity and even if you would load the node with the nid from the route parameter `node` you only get the current revision. You would have to use the route parameter `node_revision` and the storage method `loadRevision()` to get the revision you want.

You can easily resolve this by rendering the node in the node template and print the body with `{{ content.body }}`. This also removes the security problem with the `|raw` filter, which you never should use on a body field.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you point me to a reference for learning how to render the node in the node template?  {{ content.body }} currently contains more than the body field.  I appreciate any pointers as I am brand new to Drupal

Comment: You mean, the output of `{{ content.body }}` has too much html markup? If you want to change this, use a field template. If you want to target the body field use `field--body.html.twig`. Don't remove the attributes, if you want that quickedit and other modules still work. If you don't like the div's then replace them with span's.

Comment: {{ content.body }} dumps an additional img tag housing a banner img associated with the page and the title in an H2 after that.  I'm trying to grab just what was in the Body field.

Comment: This seems quite unusual for a body field. Use twig debug to see which template this is.

Comment: I have added the debugging info wrapping the extraneous fields in page.content output.  I feel quite out of my depth.

Comment: In the update you ask about a *Revision previewer*. There is no such thing, this is the node template I explained in the answer. You configure which fields and how they are displayed in the content type and probably the custom theme does some more customizing. To cover this process is far beyond the topic of the question.